# Brand logo instead of Name

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to display brand's logo instead of name in Shop by Brands Section. I am using Infortis theme. Where should I Modify?

Comment: Update you code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable brand image instead of text you need to changes setting of **`Brands`** `Show Brand Image` option of Infortis extension.

See below screen shot for detail:
[image: Setting Screen Shot]

Using this setting your theme brand slider render brand images rather than text.

Comment: I did it, but where are we uploading logo? Through CMS or media/catalog/view.phtml?

Comment: Do you have FTP? If yes then put all brand logo's under `MAGENTO_ROOT/media/wysiwyg/infortis/brands/`

Comment: if i have a product with name 'hp', can i save that image hp.png?

Comment: I guess brand is worked for product attribute rather than product itself, I mean brand should be product attribute not the whole product. Let me know what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I am actually very new to this magento. Do I need to create a new attribute 'brand' ?

Comment: No worries, please download theme user guide from [**this link**](http://infinity.nextmp.net/fileuploader/download/download/?d=0&file=custom%2Fupload%2FFile-1416260055.pdf) and refer `chapter no. 12 - Brands` which will helpful for you.